# Problem with waveform output .tr0 of hspice

Tags: simulation, waveform, hspice

I'm trying to see my project output waveform through CosMosScope but I get the error "The file format is not understood", while it gets job concluded in .lis file and simulate as well in avan waves.
I'm using HSPICE 2008 and CSCOPE 2015.
can anyone help me with this error or an app as well as cSCOPE(Freeware if possible)?
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem I had to use some .options
.options POST=2
.options AUTOSTOP
.options runlvl=3
also runlvl can be set from 1 to 6 while 6 shows the most precise respond and 1 have the fastest response

Comment: Can you please put some more effort into formatting and explanations? And use more interpunction please.